# xml parser not able to read all the nodes of the xml

Tags: iphone, nsxmlparser

Hi i am trying to get values from all the nodes of a xml returned from a web service. But debugger only runs on didStartElement api, it should go to other apis also but terminates at that point only, it does not read it further. code:

```
-(void)parseData{
NuanceAppDelegate *appDel = (NuanceAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSString *url = @"http://cmweb.bpomatrix.net/SmartPhoneService.svc/login/";
url = [[[url stringByAppendingString:UserName] stringByAppendingString:@"/"] stringByAppendingString:Password];
url = [[url stringByAppendingString:@"/"] stringByAppendingString:appDel.CPAID];
NSLog(@"log: @%",url);
NSURL *loginURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];

NSXMLParser *home_Parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:loginURL];
[home_Parser setDelegate:self];
dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[home_Parser parse];
```

}

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
```

{

```
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Address"])
    addressFound = TRUE;
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Name"])
    nameFound = TRUE;
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"LoyaltyNum"])
    loyaltyNumFound = TRUE;
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"City"])
    cityFound = TRUE;
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Province"])
    proFound = TRUE;
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Zip"])
    zipFound = TRUE;
//NSLog(@"Response %@",responseFound);
```

}

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
if(addressFound)
{
    [dict setObject:string forKey:@"address"];
    addressFound = FALSE;
}
else if(nameFound)
{
    [dict setObject:string forKey:@"name"];
    nameFound = FALSE;
}
else if(loyaltyNumFound)
{
    [dict setObject:string forKey:@"loyaltyNum"];
    loyaltyNumFound = FALSE;
}
else if(cityFound)
{
    [dict setObject:string forKey:@"city"];
    cityFound = FALSE;
}
else if(proFound)
{
    [dict setObject:string forKey:@"province"];
    proFound = FALSE;
}
else if(zipFound)
{
    [dict setObject:string forKey:@"zip"];
    zipFound = FALSE;
}
```

}

```
 - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
    {
        if([elementName isEqualToString:@"clsUserProfile"])
        {   
            [self parsingOver];
        }
    }

    - (void)parsingOver
    {
        NuanceAppDelegate *appDel = (NuanceAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        appDel.dictProfile = dict;
    }
```

Comment: sorry for ugly formating, i tried but i am not able to correct the formatting

Comment: Here is how you'd format the code http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks/22189#22189

Comment: can some one please help me, i am badly stuck......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found my mistake , was a silly one, i was not handelling debugging properly